# for which positive integer $m$ does $(ab)^{2015} = (a^2 + b^2)^m$ have positive integer solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

For which positive integers $m$ does the equation
$(ab)^{2015} = (a^2 + b^2)^m$
Have positive integer solution ?

Comment: If $m< 2015/2$ then $(a^2+b^2)^m\le (ab)^{2m} < (ab)^{2015}$ so it has no positive integral solution in that case.

Comment: If $m>2015$, then $(a^2+b^2)^m > (a^2+b^2)^{2015} \geq (ab)^{2015}$ by AM-GM.

Comment: Where did you get this question? Is it a contest problem?

Comment: My friend showed this question to me and asked me how to do it? I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be some prime dividing $b$. Then mod $p$, the equation gives that $$0\equiv a^{2m}$$ telling us that $p$ divides $a$. This implies that every prime which divides $b$ divides $a$ and vice versa. So we have 
$$\begin{align}a&=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{\alpha_i} & b&=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{\beta_i}\end{align}$$ with all the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ at least $1$.

Now write the original equation as
$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{\alpha_i+\beta_i}\right)^{2015}=\left(\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{2\alpha_i}+\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{2\beta_i} \right)^m$$
$$\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{2015\alpha_i+2015\beta_i}=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{2m\mu_i}\left(\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{2\alpha_i-2\mu_i}+\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{2\beta_i-2\mu_i} \right)^m$$ where $\mu_i=\min\{\alpha_i,\beta_i\}$. Examine the factor in parentheses with respect to one prime $p_i$.

- We can't have both summands in that factor divisible by $p_i$ or else a higher power of $p_i$ would have been distributed out.
- We can't have exactly one of the two summands in that factor still be divisible by $p_i$, because then wlog $\alpha_i>\beta_i$. Yet examining powers of $p_i$ dividing the two sides of the equation would give that $2015\alpha_i+2015\beta_i=2m\beta_i$. This would give that $$4030\beta_i<2015\alpha_i+2015\beta_i=2m\beta_i\implies m>2015$$ As pointed out in the comments to the OP, no such $m$ allow for solutions.

Therefore neither summand in that factor is divisible by $p_i$, each power of $p_i$ divides $a$ and $b$ to the same extent, each $\alpha_i=\beta_i$, and so $a=b$. And the quantity in parentheses is $(1+1)$. So the equation becomes $$\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{4030\alpha_i}=2^m\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{2m\alpha_i}\tag{$\star$}$$

Consider the powers of $2$ in this equation.  (Evidently, since $m\geq1$, $2$ is indeed a divisor of $a$, so we can agree that $2=p_1$ and use the exponent $\alpha_1$.) $$2^{4030\alpha_1}=2^{m+2m\alpha_1}=2^{m(1+2\alpha_1)}$$ So $$4030\alpha_1=m(1+2\alpha_1)$$ and since $(1+2\alpha_1)$ is coprime to $\alpha_1$, we must have that $1+2\alpha_1$ divides $4030=2\cdot5\cdot13\cdot31$. Note that $1+2\alpha_1$ is odd though. So there are $8$ numbers then that $1+2\alpha_2$ can be: $1,5,13,31,65,155,403,2015$. These lead correspondingly to $\alpha_1=0,2,6,15,32,77,201,1007$. And to $m=\frac{4030\alpha_1}{1+2\alpha_1}$ being one of $$0,1612,1860,1950,1984,2002,2010,2014.$$ Although $m=0$ is not permitted. So there are only seven possibilities for $m$, as listed. And for each of these values of $m$, we can demonstrate that $a=b=2^{m/(4030-2m)}$ is at least one integer solution set for $a$ and $b$: 
$$\begin{align}(ab)^{2015}
&=\left(2^{m/(4030-2m)}2^{m/(4030-2m)}\right)^{2015}\\
&=2^{2015m/(2015-m)}
\end{align}$$
while
$$
\begin{align}
(a^2+b^2)^m
&=\left(2^{m/(2015-m)}+2^{m/(2015-m)}\right)^m\\
&=\left(2\cdot2^{m/(2015-m)}\right)^m\\
&=\left(2^{m/(2015-m)+1}\right)^m\\
&=\left(2^{2015/(2015-m)}\right)^m\\
&=2^{2015m/(2015-m)}
\end{align}$$
In fact for these $m$, there can be no more integer solutions $(a,b)$ other than the simple powers of $2$, because equation ($\star$) reveals that if some $p\neq2$ divides $a$, then $4030\alpha_i=2m\alpha_1$, and so $m$ would have to divide $2015$. But none of the seven values for $m$ do this.

---

So $m$ must be $1612$ (with the only solution for $a$, $b$ being $a=b=2^2$), $1860$ ($a=b=2^6$), $1950$ ($a=b=2^{15}$), $1984$ ($a=b=2^{32}$), $2002$ ($a=b=2^{77}$), $2010$ ($a=b=2^{201}$), or $2014$ ($a=b=2^{1007}$).

Answer (score 0):

Easy to see that both $a$ and $b$ must be even numbers. So $a=a_1*2^p$ and $b=b_1*2^q$ where $a_1$ and $b_1$ are even numbers. Suppose $p>q$. The equation becomes:
$$
a_1^{2015}*b_1^{2015}*2^{(p+q)*2015} = (a_1^2*2^{2(p-q)} + b_1^2)^m*2^{2mq}
$$
Because $a_1$ and $b_1$ are odd numbers, we must have: 
$$
2^{(p+q)*2015} = 2^{2mq}
$$
so
$$
{2015(p+q)} = {2mq}(*)
$$
but $p>q$ and $2015 >= m$ so the (*) equality is not possible.
Let's try $p=q$:
$$
a_1^{2015}*b_1^{2015}*2^{2p*2015} = (a_1^2 + b_1^2)^m*2^{2mp}(**)
$$
because $a_1$ and $b_1$ are odd ($a_1 = 2a_2 + 1$,$b_1 = 2b_2 + 1$) so
$$
a_1^{2015}*b_1^{2015}*2^{2p*2015} = (1 + 2c)^m*2^{m(2p + 1)}
$$
and
$$
{2p*2015} = {m(2p + 1)}
$$
from there equation (**) becomes:
$$
a_1^{2015}*b_1^{2015}*2^{m} = (a_1^2 + b_1^2)^m
$$
Replacing $a_1 = 2a_2 + 1$,$b_1 = 2b_2 + 1$ again, it is easy to prove that $a_1=b_1=1$.
So $a=b=2^p$ and the given equation leads to $2p*2015=m(2p+1)$ where $2015=5*13*21$ and $2p$, $2p+1$ are coprime.